# PHP file_get_contents give error in server no in local

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I use this script for send post and get file and his contents and process the request

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'inUsername' => ''.$_REQUEST['inUsername'].'',
        'inPassword' => ''.$_REQUEST['inPassword'].'',
        'csfr_token' => ''.$_REQUEST['csfr_token'].''
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result2 = file_get_contents('http://cp.ufowebs.com/index.php', false, $context);


$result="Invalid";

if (eregi($result,$result2)) 
{
print '{"login":"ok"}';
}
else
{
print "ok";
header("Location:http://cp.ufowebs.com/index.php");v<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://cp.controlpanel.com/index.php"> 

}

}
?>
```

In local or from other url works fine , but in the same url or if go to subdomain , etc , no works and give me this error always :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/hostdata/admin/public_html/domain_com/test_cp.php on line 94 Warning: file_get_contents(http://cp.domain.com/index.php): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/hostdata/admin/public_html/domain_com/test_cp.php on line 94 ok
```

I don´t know why works from other domain and no into the same domain , etc

Comment: added `cp.domain.com` in `hosts`?

Comment: yes i put in hosts into the server right but continue the problem i dont´t know why

Comment: Ok the problem it´s csf , block this kind of connections but how i can unblock this if csf enabled ?

Comment: you mean ConfigServer Firewall & Security? you might find something in manuals. You can check if `cURL` functions work.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents` from URL is blocked in most hosts. Consult with your hosting provider if it is blocked or not.

Comment: Ok the problem it´s csf , block this kind of connections but how i can unblock this if csf enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

The domain does simply not exist.

```
nsa:~# host cp.ufowebs.com
Host cp.ufowebs.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

This is not firewall related nor is it because a disabled functionality on your server.

`ufowebs.com` does exist. If you are the owner, Mr. Klaba, you have to setup a DNS record for the subdomain or setup `*` wildcard subdomain to match any subdomain traffic.